# ExtJS Field validation preventing the cancel button click handler firing

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

Here is my textfield, the validation on blur is fine and dandy until you delete the value from this textfield, then try to press the cancel button.
1st time the validation stops the button handler from fireing so the form is never canceled.
Second time it works (i presume as the field is already dirty the validation doesn't happen).

Is there anyway to stop this nasty side effect?

```
{
    columnWidth: 0.65,
    validateOnBlur: true,
    xtype: 'coda_textfield',
    Id: 'diary_detail_description',
    allowBlank: false,
    emptyText: 'please enter something',
    name: 'taskDescription',
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function (field) {
            field.focus();
        }
 }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what not working on the first time is cause there isn't any other code.  You might want to check the `validateOnChange` config which defaults to true on fields.  http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Field-cfg-validateOnChange

Comment: Ok this one is weird, when we validate our platform puts a bar at the bottom with error messages in. Well this was moving the cancel button out of the way, so when whatever worked out where I had actually clicked i had clicked on the error bar NOT the cancel button.    So thank you very much for trying to help.

Answer (score 1):

Ok this one is weird, when we validate our platform puts a bar at the bottom with error messages in. Well this was moving the cancel button out of the way, so when whatever worked out where I had actually clicked i had clicked on the error bar NOT the cancel button.    So thank you very much for trying to help.